# Replacing DbContext.Attach()

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I've found `Attach()` to be problematic as it's tricky to mark everything needed modified. For example, if all you change is a property in Address where Address is `builder.OwnsOne(org => org.Address)`, it doesn't see it.

My use case is pretty standard. Read in an object with no tracking to populate the form. Then when they go to save(update), need to update that object and save it. But instead of using that original object, is there any downside to doing the following instead. Where this reads the object again using a tracking DbContext to update and then save?

```
public interface IPrimaryEntities
{
    public int Id { get; }
    [Timestamp]
    public byte[] RowVersion { get; set; }
}

public static async Task<T> ReloadEntityAsync<T>(this IQueryable<T> query, T entity) where T : IPrimaryEntities
{
    var reloadedEntity = await query.FirstOrDefaultAsync(e => e.Id == entity.Id);
    if (reloadedEntity == null)
    {
        throw new DbUpdateConcurrencyException($"{entity.GetType().Name} with Id={entity.Id} not found.");
    }

    if (!entity.RowVersion.SequenceEqual(reloadedEntity.RowVersion))
    {
        throw new DbUpdateConcurrencyException($"{entity.GetType().Name} with Id={entity.Id} has been modified by another user.");
    }

    return reloadedEntity;
}
```

Comment: Look at [Identity Resolution in EF Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/change-tracking/identity-resolution). There are 3 ways to do update: Call Update, Query then apply changes, Use original values.

Comment: `entity.RowVersion.SequenceEqual(reloadedEntity.RowVersion)` - imho, this is a strange and wrong way to use RowVersion. The check should take place in the sql query on the DB side.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov What led me down this path is I was constantly finding subtle bugs in my code around using `Attach()`. I came to the conclusion that using that approach, at least with me as the programmer, was always going to be buggy. Very rare subtle bugs which are the hardest to find and fix. And I do need the `DbUpdateConcurrencyException` if there's been an update/delete while the user is editing content on a page. So with those constraints, can you suggest a better alternative than what I did above? And/or, any issues with what I listed? TIA.

Answer (score 0):

After You modify an entity, it's very simple to save it to your database: before saving, You must set its state to "Modified". For example:

```
var reloadedEntity = await query.FirstOrDefaultAsync(e => e.Id == entity.Id);

reloadedEntity.Address = yourForm.Address;

YourDbContext.Entry(reloadedEntity).State = EntityState.Modified;

YourDbContext.SaveChanges();
```

...and You have to worry about the Optimistic Concurreny too, enclosing the saving operations inside a try...catch... and reloading the entity if exception occurred. You don't need to check RowVersion: SQL will do.

Comment: For a simple entity - yep. But for an entity with relationships where some objects in the collections have been modified, then it all falls apart. Attach() requires that everything be marked modified. And if you miss one - you now have a bug. Often a subtle rarely encountered bug.

Comment: If your entity has collections (childs), You must load them, and after, You mark the entity (parent) like "Modified". Alternately, You go in the childs dbset, and mark "Modified" only modified elements of your collection. There is no other choice: somehow You must say to EF which elements You want to save.

Comment: Another consideration is that using Optimistic Concurrency, if You mark "Modified" the parent entity (which has your ICollection), when You save it (inside a try catch block), someone else would like, in the same time, to edit and save the remaining items of your collection, so You can have unfortunately your transaction refused. Then the better choice is to mark like "Modified" the actually changed collection's items only.